# How to iterate over single character in a string

Tags: html, angular

How can I iterate a string using the `*ngFor`?
I have a string with binary code (e.g. 0010) and dependendig on a single bit I have to show a different icon.

```
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of subscribedCommandBus2Easy; let i = index">
   <span class="numberCircleBus2Easy col-md-2">
       {{item}}
   </span>
  <i *ngFor="let num of commandsDecimal">
    <i ng-repeat="let el in num">
     <span [ngClass]="el =='0' ? 'off-icon' : 'on-icon'">
        //is this the way I access the single character?
     </span> 
    </i>
  </i>
</div>
```

I tried this code but it does not work.

**commandsDecimal** is my array of binary string. I want to loop **commandsDecimal** at index i (suppose the element is 1010) and if the character at position y is 0 I have to show an icon otherwise the other icon and so on...

Any suggestion?

Comment: why are you using ng-repeat? it is not a part of Angular, but of AngularJs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to do a split on your string. With a custom pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'split'
})
export class SplitPipe implements PipeTransform {

   transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
     return value.split('');
   }
}
```

And then iterate over it. like that:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myString">
  <div *ngFor="let num of item | split item">
     // access num
  </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8bkywr

Comment: It could be a nice answer, but you considered commandsDecimal as a string. It is an array of string. Could you edit your answer?

Comment: I've edited it. You can optionally add a type check in your pipe or split twice one your commandsDecimal array.

Answer (score 1):

In your component typescript

```
function getSplit(string) {
    return string.split('').map(number)
}
```

In the template

```
*ngFor="let num of getSplit(commandsDecimal)"
```

Comment: A pipe would be better https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16

Comment: I was creating a stackblitz but you were faster :) Here's the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljkgxy

Comment: I do agree a custom pipe would be better if you wanna use it in multiple components, pipe is more angular way of doing it.

Comment: And then I wonder, Angular says, "pipes are a way to write display-value transformations that you can declare in your HTML". So, pipe does a transormation on the display value, not input to ngFor. How do you apply pipe to ngFor? @MoxxiManagarm

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the need for any code in your component. Also `ng-repeat` is AngularJS syntax, not Angular 2+. In Angular 2+, `ngFor` is used to iterate in the HTML.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let num of commandsDecimal">
    <i *ngFor="let el of num.split('')" [ngClass]="el === '0' ? 'off-icon' : 'on-icon'"></i>
</ng-container>
```